# iterate through json using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated!
I am having issues iterating over this json api and getting an error in my console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :, After "success": true,

How do I iterate through this json api using javascript or jquery?

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "match": [{
            "id": "87309",
            "home_name": "Viktoria Plzen U21",
            "away_name": "Slavia Praha U21",
            "score": "0 - 0",
            "ht_score": "",
            "ft_score": "",
            "et_score": "",
            "time": "26",
            "league_id": "0",
            "status": "IN PLAY",
            "added": "2018-04-23 09:05:02",
            "last_changed": "2018-04-23 09:26:01",
            "home_id": "0",
            "away_id": "0",
            "events": false,
            "league_name": null
        },
        {
            "id": "87308",
            "home_name": "Karvina U21",
            "away_name": "Slovan Liberec U21",
            "score": "1 - 0",
            "ht_score": "",
            "ft_score": "",
            "et_score": "",
            "time": "26",
            "league_id": "0",
            "status": "IN PLAY",
            "added": "2018-04-23 09:05:02",
            "last_changed": "2018-04-23 09:26:01",
             "home_id": "0",
            "away_id": "0",
            "events": false,
            "league_name": null
        }]
    }
}
```

and the code so far:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'JSONP',
    jsonpCallback: 'callbackFnc',
    type: 'GET',
    async: false,
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) { },
    failure: function () { },
    complete: function (data) {
        if (data.readyState == '4' && data.status == '200') {
            if (data.match) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.match.length; i++) {
                    console.log( data.match[i].id );
                }
            }
        } else {
            errorLog.push({ IP: Host, Status: 'FAIL' })
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Do a `console.log( data);` and iterate accordingly. may be yo need `console.log(data.data.match[i].id)`

Comment: may be you need to access response in success()

Comment: Looks like response contain data {} as a part of json so you have to use data.data.match[i].